# Why the legend border is not displayed in victory chart?

Tags: victory-charts

This is my jsfiddle url. Could you help to find out why the border of   legend can not display in this chart. The legend related code was copied from official document site.
Below is my legend component.

```
<VictoryLegend x={75} y={0}
    title="Legend"
    centerTitle
    orientation="horizontal"
    gutter={20}
    style={{ border: { stroke: "black" }, title: { fontSize: 20 } }}
    data={legendData}
  />





https://jsfiddle.net/xuhang1128/xwy8j4fw/1/
```

Comment: How Can I correctly include jsfiddle here?

Comment: What version of Victory are you using?